# Should I be using Docker to config a kernel or just the services running on the kernel?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have a web server running CentOS, with PHP and MySQL installed. I want to set up a git repository for developing with others, so I thought it would be appropriate to learn to use Docker for making the development process more consistent among developers. Currently I have separate containers for PHP and MySQL, and a docker-compose.yml file which has php and mysql as services (with build paths to the PHP and MySQL Dockerfiles).

Is there any value in also having a container for CentOS, as the developers would potentially be developing on all manner of operating systems? My understanding of Docker is that I can use it to specify consistent configuration of all the various services which the app depends on, which suggests to me that there may be value in also configuring the operating system/kernel to make that consistent as well.

Comment: What type of kernel configuration are you thinking on?

Comment: @Robert anything. CentOS version would be the main thing I can think of, because any dependencies could be handled by the other containers (if I understand correctly).